# "dpkg: error: --install option does not take a value"

Tags: debian, dpkg

Clearly, `dpkg --install` *does* take a value, the package to install. And running just that `dpkg --install` without a value produces the expected error

> dpkg: error: --install needs at least one package archive file
>   argument

But given that the error message is literally nonsense, then what is causing the problem? The end result is that the build procedure fails, the package built is not installed, and the build log leaves just this as a clue to the error.

Things I've checked:

- Passing a file which doesn't exist gives the correct error message "No such file or directory"
- Running as non-root gives "requested operation requires superuser privilege"
- Using `--install=package.deb` doesn't fix the problem (the `--help` is ambiguous whether you need an = sign for values, and it appears this is correct. Some arguments do, others don't).

Comment: You don't actually give any information about the failed  build. Can you at least include the command you used and the error messages?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dpkg/dpkg.1) does specify when `=` should be used. For example:

> `-i`, `--install` package-file...

(no `=`) v.

> `--abort-after=`number

The error message you’re seeing is displayed when you try `dpkg --install=` (with or without a value).

You need to run `dpkg -i package` or `dpkg --install package`, with a space, not `=`.

Comment: Actually, that's specifically why I added the last bullet. I did follow the the instructions and did **not** add an =. Since that caused the problem described, I first tried a few alternatives before opening a question, and one of the things I tried was to see if adding an = helped. (no).

Comment: OK, I wondered about that. AFAICT though the *only* way to get the error message you’re seeing is to run `dpkg --install=` (even without a value)...